# Passing current ADO Record to another function

Tags: vba, vb6, adodb

Perhaps I've spent too much time in .NET, but it seems odd that I cannot easily pass the current Record of an ADO RecordSet to another method.

```
Private Sub ProcessData(data As ADODB.Recordset)
    While (Not data.EOF)
        ProcessRecord ([data.CurrentRecord]) ' <-- There is no CurrentRecord property.
        data.MoveNext        
    Wend
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessRecord(singleRecord As ADODB.Record)
    ' Do stuff.
End Sub
```

The scant info I've found on the subject says to pass the entire RecordSet or to create a new Record and manually copy each field to it.

StackOverflow, is there a better way?

Comment: A record is not a recordset, you can select a single record as a recordset, or you can pass a record or records from a recordset as an array (GetRows ) or string ( [GetString](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_getstring.asp) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would pass the entire recordset in to the ProcessRecord subroutine.  Recordsets are always passed by reference so there is no overhead (performance or memory consumption) passing a recordset around.  Just make sure you don't move to the next record in the ProcessRecord subroutine.

Comment: I'll most likely just pass the whole RecordSet, it's just that `ProcessRecord` has no business knowing about all the data.  I strive to feed methods only what they need.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the GetRows() method to load the data into an array and then let ProcessRecord work only with the array, but that 'disconnects' the method from the dataset and this may not be what you intend.

The GetRows() method takes optional arguments to specify how many rows to get, where to start and the fields to get

So:

ProcessRecord(data.GetRows(1,adBookmarkCurrent))

should do it for all fields

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.. you cant extract a single Record from a Recordset.. as G. Mastros said there is no additional overhead passing the whole recordset by reference and work with the current record so you might as well do it like that